# auth0 Multiple Environments and multiple user communities

Tags: auth0

the company I work for has 3 environments (development, staging and production) and 3 types of users (consumer, employee and partners)

Should we create 9 tenants?

1. dev/consumer
2. dev/employee
3. dev/partners
4. stg/consumer
5. stg/employee
6. stg/partners
7. prod/consumer
8. prod/employee
9. prod/partners

Comment: Yes, please! I'm looking for the same answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hey there Rodolfo I work with the Auth0 Community and it's recommended to create separate tenants per each environment.

> Development, Test, QA environments are easy to setup in Auth0. Simply
>   create a new tenant for each to guarantee the maximum isolation
>   between these environments. You can easily switch between tenants
>   using the tenant chooser from the top right menu on the dashboard. You
>   can also configure different administrators for each.

https://auth0.com/docs/dev-lifecycle/setting-up-env

Thanks, Jim!